# Desperately trying to make Watin work with IE

Tags: timeout, internet-explorer-9, watin

I have been working with Watin for about 1 week. I really wanted to make firefox work but had to give up after a day or so when seeing there was no way i could get jSSH working with Firefox 8 etc. Really wish there was a way of using Chrome or firefox i have to say

So returning reluctantly to IE I developed some automation software using Watin, however I have a persistent problem with Goto(href) where it seems as though the page never actually gets marked as complete. And although the browser navigates to the page and I can see the page fine, the call to Goto() just times out. After that point anything I try fails and it cant find the elements in the dom and I cant click anything programmatically. So I have to solve this timeout issue

I have read various articles suggesting fixes and have tried them all as far as I can see i.e. making sure I run as administrator, making sure that internet explorer enhanced security is switched off, etc.. I would really, really like to make Watin work - but right now I am about ready to give up and create a much, much simpler class with an embedded browser in my app. So stackoverflow is my last port of call. How can I stop Watin from timing out.

I am on Windows 7 Ultimate Version 6.1.7601 Service pack 1 build 7601
Visual Studio 2010
compiling as a .net 4.0 app
IE 9.0.8112.16421 with update KB2586448
I have a console app, no threads, [STAThread] on my Main entry point

This is my Visual Studio info:-

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel
Microsoft Visual C# 2010   01021-532-2002102-70185

Any help will be very greatfully received.

Regards Julian

Comment: So you're using Goto() then calling browser.WaitForComplete() which is timing out?  Does this happen on all pages or just the page specific to your app?

Comment: GoTo() times out when going to www.asda.com, i think, perhaps, it's because the web page contains a set of frames. But once a timeout has occurred everything fails thereafter. I have spent much of the afternoon fighting with this as I really want to make it work. I have done a svn checkout of the latest code and compiled that which is behaving better. - I am very much looking forward to Jeroen completing IE9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, so after many months of playing and fiddling the answer to my question has several parts.

Firstly. I needed to get Watin working properly as an embedded browser in a win32 application rather than as a console app. This required me to spend a huge amount of effort getting Watin embedded the way I wanted, I had problems with STATHREAD (of course), and the pop up dialog watcher, and getting the HWND of my browser into Watin to create its browser object (I used another sample on stack overflow to do this) and then I had to ensure ScriptErrorsSuppressed=true and I finally got it working. Hoorah

However, the problem I originally had all that time ago still seems to remain with Watin.2.1.0.1196 in dealing with frame sets on asda.com.

So I have just now done a svn checkout of the watin project and I am finally hoping that the latest updates I have seen will fix this problem once and for all... and Yes I am still really looking forward to Jeroen getting IE9 or indeed any other browser working with Watin. Working with IE (any flavour) sucks

Answer (score 1):

WaTiN does not support IE9 fully yet as far as I know. Jeroen (the creator) is working on getting it fully compatible with IE9, but IE9 relies on new WPF components in regards to previous versions of IE, so i'm guessing this will take some work.

We suffered from several problems as well when we upgraded our WatiN tests to IE9. In the end we force our website to render everything to IE8 standards and set IE9 to IE8 rendering mode untill there is an update from watin to fully support IE9 with all its quirkcs and features.

Comment: I do not use IE, I use opera/chrome/firefox - I am interested in exploring your suggestion so how does one change IE9 to IE8 rendering mode? maybe that will help me

Comment: We place a certain class/id in the body of the html and force javascript etc to work with that. It's like in js for checking your browser version.
IE itself has also a setting , think it's called the compatibility render or something